# And the wheel keeps on turning

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

**Across**
1. Ask me about glacial landforms (5)
4. Invalidate start of automobile race's first round (7)
9. Luciferous phenomenon shown by conservative TV network, with strong displeasure (7)
10. Someone from around here wrote: "Richard III flipped out, making a scene of astronomical proportions" (4)
11. Straggling serpent with crude, powerful tail (7)
13. Maybe *The Big Sleep* stars retired after being refused the lead in *Oklahoma!* (4)
15. Leaving Greek capital, move to Kuwait? (7)
16. James Bond essentially disappeared from Indiana's east (5)
21. In back woods live Ewoks, tiny creatures that eat grain (7)
22. American rock group covers mostly peaceful ceremony (7)
25. Nuclear power unit discarded by Victor (5)
26. Musician's less than stellar backing (7)
28. Star, say, turned away from what looks like an oasis in the desert? (4)
29. Magic child succeeds Jack in official documents, perhaps (7)
30. Media person reported embarrassing segment from the east (4)
31. Playing bingo with lowlife? Extremely dishonourable (7)
32. Occur at a time before hunt (7)
33. In what situation is whiskey present? (5)

**Down**
1. Asian ruler causes offence showing pieces of traditional weaponry (8)
2. Gloomy Polish criminal changed size (6)
3. Adolphe drinking fine port (4)
4. In broadcast, I evaluate method for contemporary artist (2,6)
5. Runner Farah refused to make profit from new website visitor? (7)
6. Tours' #1 cooking appliance has advertisement which is not demonstrably correct (8)
7. Devoted young adult is locked inside? That's funny (5)
8. Wipe out announcer's team from the Sunshine State (4)
12. Senior has chatted incessantly – he might creep you out (7)
14. Dictionary briefly brought up identical word for health concerns (7)
17. Female in team is under pressure (8)
18. Taking part of one, no time showing up for a second? (8)
19. Cut off relations with Engineer Sergeant (8)
20. Lost in the battlefield, surrounded, I left Italian army (7)
23. Cause separation from spouse, at one extreme, with almost 100% silent treatment (6)
24. Be in expectation to obtain Sinatra's debut track (1-4)
26. Sign of baby being behind piano (4)
27. Say hello to get food (4)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solved grid should look like this:

> [image: Solved grid?]

Solutions to individual clues:

> **Across**
>  1. Ask me about **glacial landforms** (5) **[KAMES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kame)** = ASKME*
>  4. Invalidate start of automobile race's first **round** (7) **ANNULAR** = ANNUL (Invalidate)  + A(-utomobile) + R(-ace)
>  9. **Luciferous phenomenon** shown by conservative TV network, with strong displeasure (7) **[FOXFIRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foxfire)** = FOX (conservative TV network) + F (strong) + IRE (displeasure)
>  10. Someone from around here wrote: "Richard III flipped out, making **a scene of astronomical proportions**" (4) **NOVA** = [AVON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_Avon,_Warwickshire)< (i.e. Shakespeare, author of *Richard III* was from Stratford-upon-Avon...) (thanks @GarethMcCaughan in comments)
>  11. **Straggling** serpent with crude, powerful tail (7) **ASPRAWL** = ASP (serpent) + RAW (crude) + (-powerfu)L
>  13. **Maybe *The Big Sleep*** stars retired after being refused the lead in *Oklahoma!* (4) **[NOIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_noir)** = (-o)RION<
>  15. Leaving Greek capital, move to **Kuwait?** (7) **EMIRATE** = EMI(-g)RATE
>  16. **James** Bond essentially disappeared from [Indiana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Jones)'s east (5) **[JESSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesse_James)** = J(-_on_)ES'S + E (east)
>  21. In back woods live Ewoks, **tiny creatures that eat grain** (7) **WEEVILS** = _S LIVE EW_<
>  22. American rock group covers mostly peaceful **ceremony** (7) **REQUIEM** = RE(QUIE(-t))M
>  25. **Nuclear** power unit discarded by Victor (5) **INNER** = (-w)INNER
>  26. **Musician**'s less than stellar backing (7) **BASSIST** = B (a grade that's 'less than stellar') + ASSIST
>  28. **Star**, say, turned away from what looks like an oasis in the desert? (4) **[MIRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mira)** = MIRA(-EG<)
>  29. **Magic** child succeeds Jack in official documents, perhaps (7) **[JOHNSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Johnson)** JOHN (Jack in official documents, perhaps) + SON (child)
>  30. **Media person** reported embarrassing segment from the east (4) **[MEDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_(region))** = _ED EM_<
>  31. Playing bingo with lowlife? Extremely **dishonourable** (7) **IGNOBLE** = BINGO* + L(-owlif)E
>  32. **Occur at a time before | hunt** (7) **PREDATE** = ddef
>  33. **In what situation** is whiskey present? (5) **WHERE** = W (Whiskey) + HERE (present)
>
>  **Down**
>  1. Asian ruler causes offence showing **pieces of traditional weaponry** (8) **[KHANJARS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khanjar)** = KHAN + JARS
>  2. **Gloomy** Polish criminal changed size (6) **MOPISH** = PO(L->M)ISH*
>  3. Adolphe drinking fine **port** (4) **[SFAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sfax)** = S(F)AX
>  4. In broadcast, I evaluate method for **contemporary artist** (2,6) **[AI WEIWEI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ai_Weiwei)** = "I weigh way"
>  5. Runner Farah refused to make profit from new **website visitor?** (7) **NETIZEN** = (-[mo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mo_Farah))NETIZE + N (new)
>  6. Tours' #1 cooking appliance has advertisement which is **not demonstrably correct** (8) **UNPROVEN** = UN ('1' in Tours, France) + PR (advertisement) + OVEN (cooking appliance)
>  7. **Devoted** young adult is locked inside? That's funny (5) **LOYAL** = LO(YA)L
>  8. **Wipe out** announcer's team from the Sunshine State (4) **RAZE** = (Tampa Bay) "[Rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tampa_Bay_Rays)"
>  12. Senior has chatted incessantly – **he might creep you out** (7) **STALKER** = SR (senior) containing TALKE(-d)
>  14. Dictionary briefly brought up identical word for **health concerns** (7) **OEDEMAS** = OED (Dictionary briefly) + SAME<
>  17. Female in team is **under pressure** (8) **SQUASHED** = SQUA(SHE)D
>  18. Taking part of one, no time showing up for **a second?** (8) **[SEMITONE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semitone#Minor_second)** = _E NO TIME S_<
>  19. **Cut off relations with** Engineer Sergeant (8) **ESTRANGE** = SERGEANT*
>  20. Lost in the battlefield, surrounded, I left Italian **army** (7) **MILITIA** = MIA (Lost in the battlefield) surrounding I + L + IT
>  23. **Cause separation from** spouse, at one extreme, with almost 100% silent treatment (6) **ENISLE** = (-spous)E + SILEN(-t)*
>  24. Be in expectation to obtain Sinatra's debut **track** (1-4) **B-SIDE** = B(S)IDE
>  26. **Sign of baby** being behind piano (4) **BUMP** = BUM (behind) + P (piano)
>  27. Say hello to get **food** (4) **CHOW** = "ciao"

Comment: 10a is rot13(gur erirefr bs NIBA, naq fbzrbar sebz nebhaq gurer jebgr _Evpuneq VVV_).

Comment: Oh, and one of your links is major where it should be minor.

Comment: Ah yes, of course, thanks @GarethMcCaughan :) (I was so deep into trying to alter the letters of 'NATIVE' to see this...)